# meta_query only check if both value are set

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have an age filter, where it checks two custom fields, `min_age` and `max_age`, `max_age` is optional so it can be empty.

These don't seem to work together:

```
    array(
      'key'     => 'max_age',
      'value'   => $max_age,
      'type' => 'numeric',
      'compare' => '<=',
    ),
    array(
      'key'     => 'max_age',
      'value'   => '',
      'compare' => '!=',
    )
```

If I remove the top array (<= filter), it returns the correct results, only showing results with the correct min_age and results that have a max_age value. How can I make them work together because the `!= '' max_age` filter is needed, otherwise the `max_age` <= filter doesn't work correctly because it ignores that filter if the max_age custom field is empty.

```
      $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'key'     => 'min_age',
          'value'   => $min_age,
          'type' => 'numeric',
          'compare' => '>=',
        ),
        array(
          'key'     => 'max_age',
          'value'   => $max_age,
          'type' => 'numeric',
          'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        array(
          'key'     => 'max_age',
          'value'   => '',
          'compare' => '!=',
        )
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset` to check if the values are set, and then pass them as arguments. Divide your query by 2 parts and use them as needed.

```
// Check if both are set 
if ( isset( $max_age ) && isset( $min_age ) ) {
    $meta_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'key'     => 'min_age',
          'value'   => $min_age,
          'type' => 'numeric',
          'compare' => '>=',
        ),
        array(
          'key'     => 'max_age',
          'value'   => $max_age,
          'type' => 'numeric',
          'compare' => '<=',
        ),
        array(
          'key'     => 'max_age',
          'value'   => '',
          'compare' => '!=',
        )
    );
} else {
    $meta_query = array(
        array(
          'key'     => 'min_age',
          'value'   => $min_age,
          'type' => 'numeric',
          'compare' => '>=',
        )
    );
}
// Now set the query
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

If both `$min_age` and `$max_age` are always set and you want to check if they are empty or not, you can use `empty()` instead of `isset()`.

Comment: $min_age and $max_age are filters passed to this, this would not work as I need to check if the actual post has values for min_age and max_age custom fields.